# Extension cord to Power strip in old house

Tags: cables, electrical

I live in a old house that has very old wiring. We got a small upgrade so we now have grounded outlets. I need to plug in a lot of devices into this outlet such as speakers, monitor and a gaming computer. So I bought the longest power strip I could find since I need to stretch it to my desk. But it is not long enough. My question is, is it dangerous to plug a power strip into a extension cord? In a old house that has old wiring and does not have many amps? Would I need a high rated extension cord?

Comment: This question may be better in the DIY group.  They deal with AC wiring problems (among many other DIY/home repair topics).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to DIY.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension cord and power strip must be rated for the total power you expect to use.

If you intend to plug in phone or notebook chargers (and even desktop computers) you'll probably run out of outlets long before you overload things (unless you use a very light-duty extension). Laser printers are fairly heavy loads (mine draws about 7 Amps when printing).